# How to use multiple instances of a variable next to each other?

Tags: python

I don't really know how to describe it any better, but I need to write a program that answers this question:

> Write a loop that computes the value of a + aa + aaa + aaaa with a given digit as the value of a.

Any advice?

Comment: Any attempt? (Yourself)

Comment: I have not. I don't know where to go with this, and I can't think of anything that could put a variable next to itself without producing an error.

Comment: Try multiplying by 11, 111, 1111....

Comment: Or convert it to a string, and use string addition.

Comment: Perhaps you better first try to implement something, but without a loop, then you look for generalities, and try to "push up" the concept to a `while` loop.

Comment: Indeed, start writing something that calculates a+aa. Hint: a+aa = a * 1 + a * 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using a (slightly complicated) list comprehension:

```
number = 1
length = 4
sum(int(str(number) * i) for i in range(1,length+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest I could think of

```
digit = "1"

result = sum([int("{}".format(digit * x)) for x in [1,2,3]])
print(result)
# 123
```

This repeats the string (sic!) `x` times, converts the result to an integer and sums the parts up to `result`.